# Android - BroadcastReceiver is not firing when application starts again

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-broadcast

I have a service which fetches location periodically and broadcasts data to my activity where I have registered a BroadcastReceiver.I unregister my BroadcastReceiver when I close my application.That location service will be running continuously in the background though my application is not running.I want to receive broadcasted data again to my activity(after registering BroadcastReceiver again) from that previously started service if I start my application again.

Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: show us the code where you register and unregister u BroadcastReceiver

Comment: public void registerLocationServiceReceiver(){
  
 broadcastReceiver = new LocationServiceReceiver();
 IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
 filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_USER_FOREGROUND);              
 registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, filter);
}
 
public void unregisterLocationServiceReceiver(){
 unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
}

Comment: You can just run this function in onResume() method or so..It should work..Your service will broadcast an event and Android will make sure to deliver it to all registered receivers with matching intent filters

Comment: Hey, please let me know if you found the solution for this issue. I am facing the same issue. @simekadam, the code is in a service. onResume won't work there

Comment: I tried putting the code in the Application class and it worked! atleast the ACTION_USER_BACKGROUND. However i did not get the broadcast receiver for ACTION_USER_FOREGROUND.